# ubuntu-touch: some unknown uid and gid on system files

Tags: ubuntu, files

I have this strange situation in ubuntu-touch

```
    65097     12 drwxrwxr-x   3 1005     1006        12288 Feb 23 00:34 /etc/init
    10548      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 1005     1006         4096 Aug 12  1972 /etc/wifi
    10549      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 1005     1006         2442 Oct 27 22:26 /etc/wifi/bcmdhd.cal
    10500      4 drwxrwxr-x  11 1005     1006         4096 Oct 27 22:26 /var
    32845      4 drwxrwxr-x  55 1005     1006         4096 Feb  6 09:42 /var/lib
    32941      4 drwxrwxr-x   3 1005     1006         4096 Oct 27 22:26 /var/lib/lxc
    32942      4 drwxrwxr-x   5 1005     1006         4096 Feb 23 00:34 /var/lib/lxc/android
    76201 113908 -rw-r--r--   1 1005     1006     116523008 Oct 27 22:26 /var/lib/lxc/android/system.img
       13      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 1005     1006            83 Oct 27 22:26 /var/lib/lxc/android/rootfs/cache/legacy_channel
   539667      4 drwxrwx---   2 1005     audio         4096 Aug 12  1972 /var/lib/lxc/android/rootfs/data/misc/audio
       13      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 1005     1006            83 Oct 27 22:26 /android/cache/legacy_channel
   539667      4 drwxrwx---   2 1005     audio         4096 Aug 12  1972 /android/data/misc/audio
    80017     32 drwxrwxr-x   2 1005     1006         32768 Feb 23 00:34 /usr/bin
    84183      4 -rw-rw-r--   1 1005     1006           194 Oct 27 22:26 /usr/bin/.system-image-keep
    98722      4 drwxrwxr-x 171 1005     1006          4096 Feb  6 09:45 /usr/share
    99023      4 drwxrwxr-x   2 1005     1006          4096 Aug 12  1972 /usr/share/bluetooth-touch
   100367      4 -rwxrwxr-x   1 1005     1006           702 Oct 27 22:26 /usr/share/bluetooth-touch/hammerhead
   115235      4 -rw-r--r--   1 1005     root           904 Apr  8  2021 /usr/share/system-image/archive-master.tar.xz
   115236      4 -rw-r--r--   1 1005     root           488 Apr  8  2021 /usr/share/system-image/archive-master.tar.xz.asc
   539667      4 drwxrwx---   2 1005     audio         4096 Aug 12  1972 /userdata/android-data/misc/audio
```

I can safely give the correct permissions(755 and root:root) or can cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found(in the ubports forum).
Is better to not touch permissions because the android "subsystem" need the "strange" permissions to works.